# Error authenticating with LDAP in Spring Boot Reason: [LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights]

Tags: java, spring-boot, openldap

I am trying to make a validation page with spring boot that validates user that exists in an LDAP server. My code is this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.LdapShaPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchBase("ou=people")
        .userSearchFilter("(cn={0})")
        .contextSource(contextSource())
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource(){
    return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:389"),"dc=myCompany,dc=org");
}
```

}

The problem is that I am getting the following error and I don't seem to understand where it is coming from.

> Reason: [LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights]; nested exception is javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights]; remaining name 'cn=nameEntered,ou=people'

Any help would helpful.

Comment: I would put my money on you not having the permissions to query the LDAP user using your ldap credentials. It clearly tells you that you have Insufficient Access Rights to be running that LDAP query.

Comment: Another option is to turn on the debug logs for spring security and look for log messages related to ldap.

Comment: @horatius Thank for the reply. Why don't I have the permissions? Only admin has them ? And how can I get the permission ? I can query LDAP from my terminal anyway.

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG  I can't see any error message other than what I've stated --->  javax.naming.NoPermissionException:

Comment: How are you querying LDAP from the command line? Are you also getting the userPassword attribute on the command line like you're trying to get from Spring? This attribute is normally protected on most LDAP servers.

Comment: Like ldapsearch -xLLL -b "dc=companyName,dc=org". Hhmm no... I am not using userPassword in terminal tbh.

Comment: @Stefanos LDAP is covered by spring security. So your log settings should be logging.level.org.springframework.security: DEBUG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely with you trying to pull userPassword as part of the LDAP search query. Most servers protect this attribute as described in [this RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-stroeder-hashed-userpassword-values-01.html#rfc.section.2).

So there's potentially two different solutions to this problem:

- Talk to your LDAP server administrator and create a process account capable of reading that attribute ([manual for OpenLDAP here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Centralized_authentication_using_OpenLDAP#Access_management_.28ACLs.29)). This assumes your userPassword attribute is a cleartext password, if it's not you'll need to use a password encoder as [described here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/).
- Switch to bind authentication. Instead of using a privileged account to retrieve the password from the user this binds to LDAP as the user you're trying to authenticate as which doesn't require any special permissions. It would only give you access to attributes the user has access to however. This is [described here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161121082619/https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/ldap.html#using-bind-authentication). You can configure it like this:

`<ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people"/>`

In either case you should probably switch to ldaps:// instead of ldap:// since passwords (or hashes) will be going over the network in the clear.

Comment: This could have been an awesome answer if the solution was included instead of just linked to. The link destination is no longer available.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a link to the archived page, also included the relevant configuration sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Spring API.

But I read the API call as this does two things:

1. Send a search operation for getting the distinguished name (DN) of the user's LDAP entry.
2. Send a compare operation for this DN with assertion type *userPassord* and the input password as assertion value.

One of this operations fail. Which one can be probably seen in the exception traceback.

In any case validating a password with a compare operation against OpenLDAP makes no sense because it only works when storing clear-text password. That's something skilled LDAP admins likely don't do.

So try to find the API method for using a bind operation for checking the password for the located user DN. Note that this might require to use a system account authentication in your client application for getting search results.

There are cases where you can directly derive a user DN from a username. In this case you could just send the bind operation without prior system binding. But this requires a fixed directory information tree (DIT) layout.